# Subset data by group by proportion in SAS

Tags: sas, subset, sampling

In this data, I need to subset by each variable by certain percentage.
For example,

```
Obs Group Score
1     A    1
2     A    2
3     B    1
4     B    1
5     C    3
6     C    1
7     C    1
8     A    1
9     A    3
10    A    1
11    A    2
12    B    3
13    C    2
```

I would need to subset 10 obs.
The sample must consist of all groups, and score of 1 takes higher priority.
Each group is given certain percent.
Let say 50% for A, 20% for B and 30% for C.

I tried using proc surveyselect but it failed. The number of alloc is not same as the strata.

```
proc surveyselect data=example out=test sampsize=10;
strata group score/alloc=(0.5 0.2 0.3);
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know `proc surveyselect` too much, so I give the data step version.

```
data have;
    input Obs Group$ Score;
    cards;
1     A    1
2     A    2
3     B    1
4     B    1
5     C    3
6     C    1
7     C    1
8     A    1
9     A    3
10    A    1
11    A    2
12    B    3
13    C    2
;
run;

proc sort;
    by Group Score;
run;

data want;

    array _Dist_[3]$ _temporary_('A','B','C');
    array _Upper_[3] _temporary_(5,2,3);
    array _Count_[3] _temporary_;

    do i = 1 to rec;
        set have nobs=rec point=i;
        do j = 1 to dim(_Dist_);
            _Count_[j] + (Group=_Dist_[j]);
            if _Count_[j] <= _Upper_[j] and Group = _Dist_[j] then output;
        end;
    end;
    stop;
    drop j;
run;
```